# How can I access my XML layouts from within an Android AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask in my app. When a method completes in the asynctask, I show a custom Toast (success or failure). The following class works well:

```
public class SendForm extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean>{
    private String message;
    private String sender;
    private Context context;

    public SendForm(String message, String sender, Context context){
        this.message = message;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
        Boolean success = false;
        MyMessageSender myMessageSender = new MyMessageSender();
        try {
            myMessageSender.send(message, sender);
            success = true
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.i.(SendForm.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return success
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean formSent){
        super.onPostExecute(formSent);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.BLACK);
        layout.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
        LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
        container.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        container.setPadding(10,8,10,8);
        TextView textview = new TextView(context);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textview.setTextSize(24);
        textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
        imageview.setPadding(0,0,10,0);

        if(formSent){
            textview.setText("Form Successfully Sent");
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.color.WHITE);
        } else {
            textview.setText("Error Sending Form");
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.xmark);
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.color.LIGHTPINK);
        }

        container.addView(imageview);
        container.addView(textview);

        layout.addView(container);

        Toast statusToast = new Toast(context);
        statusToast.setView(layout);
        statusToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 50);
        statusToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        statusToast.show();
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works perfectly, but I would like to make it easier to maintain. So, I created two XML layouts form_success.xml

```
<?xml ?>
<LinearLayout andriod:id="@+id/form_success_layout">
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

and form_error.xml

```
<?xml ?>
<LinearLayout andriod:id="@+id/form_error_layout">
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I changed my SendForm.java to this

```
public class SendForm extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean>{
    private String message;
    private String sender;
    private Context context;

    public SendForm(String message, String sender, Context context){
        this.message = message;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
        Boolean success = false;
        MyMessageSender myMessageSender = new MyMessageSender();
        try {
            myMessageSender.send(message, sender);
            success = true
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.i.(SendForm.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return success
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean formSent){
        super.onPostExecute(formSent);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        Toast statusToast = new Toast(context);

        if(formSent){
            linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.form_success_layout);
            statusToast.setView(linearLayout);
        } else {
            linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.form_error_layout);
            statusToast.setView(linearLayout);
        }

        statusToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 50);
        statusToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        statusToast.show();
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. I do not get an error of any kind, it just quietly does not work.

What do I need to do in order to use these two external XML files as opposed to building the Toast the way I currently have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inflate the layouts. Please read about LayoutInflater:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: I tried `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` and then `inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_success);` but I need a **ViewGroup** and I am not sure how to get hold of one.

Comment: you do not need a viewgroup ( allthough you have one ) - please read the documentation

Comment: Ok ... that worked really well. Like I said, I tried `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` then I tried `statusToast.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_success, null));` and it worked just as before. Thank you for the assistance. Have a great day!

Comment: you also have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by inflating your layout in onPostExecuteMethod.

```
LinearLayour parentFrame =  (LinearLayour)findViewById(R.id.parentFrame );
     final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View view;
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_success, null);
      parentFrame.addView(view);
```

Then get ImageView like this way.

```
     LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)parentFrame.getChild(0);
     ImageView img = (ImageView)linearLayout.getChild(0);
     TextView txt = (TextView)linearLayout.getChild(1);
```

Where parent frame is the MainFrame of your activity like below pseudoCode.

```
<LinearLayout 
id ="parentFrame"
width = "match_parent"
height = "wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: `findViewById()` is not available to me in onPostExecuteMethod

Comment: its just finding the reference of your layout and you can move this line to Oncreate Method and make parentFrame global variable.

Comment: @Brian, did you try to put ((Activity)context).findViewById()?

Comment: After my AsyncTask is complete, the calling activity calls `finish()` to send me back to the previous activity.

Comment: Send parentFrame view as a parameter in this Asynctask then use it in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

you have not added any child to the parent LinearLayout and yet you are accessing child views from it.The following will return null

```
linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.form_success_layout);
```

Use the following instead:

```
int layout = formSent ? R.layout.form_success_layout : R.layout.form_error_layout;    
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout,null,false);
statusToast.setView(view);
```

Comment: When I try your method, I get an error `Expected resource of type layout` error on the section `inflate(layout,null,false)` for "layout" being an int.